# Populate username/password in webpage with Powershell

Tags: html, powershell, authentication

I'm trying to populate the username and password in a Motorola router's login page. Partial HTML of the page is below:

```html
<form name="login" onsubmit="return loginSubmit()" action="/goform/login" method="POST"> 
  <div id="moto-login">

    <some divs snipped>

    <div id="moto-username">
    <input name="loginUsername" class="moto-username-input" onfocus="onFocusUsername()" onblur="onBlurUsername()" type="text" value="Username">
    </div>

    <some divs snipped>

  </div>
</form>
```

I'm using PowerShell, and trying to get a handle on the value string. I can do this:

```
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("moto-username").innerHTML
```

And get this:

```html
<input name="loginUsername" class="moto-username-input" onfocus="onFocusUsername()" onblur="onBlurUsername()" type="text" value="Username">
```

…but I can't see how to set the variables. Is this due to the nesting of `<div>`s?

I've tried various forms, such as:

```
$iePPM.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("moto-username") = "myusername"
```

…but nothing is working.

TIA!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that I get this: 

<input name="loginUsername" class="moto-username-input" onfocus="onFocusUsername()" onblur="onBlurUsername()" type="text" value="Username">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully populate the username and password fields and click the button with:

$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("loginUsername").value = "admin"
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("loginPassword").value = "password"
$Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | Where-Object {$_.type -eq 'submit'}
$Link.click()

Answer (score 0):

You are not saying how you are discovering/scraping for your elements.

If you did this ...

... what comes back as elements?

Example(s):

For your site - To be sure. Navigate the site form elements, not the Internet Explorer elements

```
$url = 'https://pwpush.com'

($FormElements = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -SessionVariable fe)   

<#
    StatusCode        : 200
    StatusDescription : OK
    Content           : <!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html>
...
#>



($Form = $FormElements.Forms[0]) | 
Format-List -Force

<#
    Id     : new_password
    Method : post
    Action : /p
    Fields : ...}
#>

$Form | 
Get-Member

<#
       TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormObject

    Name        MemberType   Definition                                                        
    ----        ----------   ----------                                                        
    Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                    
    GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()                                                 
    GetType     Method       type GetType()                                                    
    ToString    Method       string ToString()                                                 
    Action      Property     string Action {get;}                                              
    Fields      Property     System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string] Fields {get;}
    Id          Property     string Id {get;}                                                  
    Method      Property     string Method {get;}                                              
    MSDN        ScriptMethod System.Object MSDN();
#>

$Form.Fields

<#
    Key                          Value                                                                                   
    ---                          -----                                                                                   
    utf8                         ✓                                                                                       
    authenticity_token           2mebmGbAJsseDW+/TeTBXAelq1s8kH5Zgb6W14Pxtba6CyWsAM4SfVqdJWdVmu5HjxIGUCWjEGhy6fLTB38UhA==
    password_payload             Enter the Password to be Shared                                                         
    password_expire_after_days   7                                                                                       
    password_expire_after_views  5                                                                                       
    password_deletable_by_viewer on                                                                                      
    commit                       Push it!
```

Or just view site source on the page

```
<# 
    <span class='note'>
    (whichever comes first)
    </span>
...
#>


# so you end up here

Clear-Host

$password = '1234'
$loginUrl = 'https://pwpush.com'

$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($loginUrl)

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 }

($ie.document.getElementById('password_payload') | select -first 1).value = $password
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 

$ie.Document.getElementsByName('commit').Item().Click();
Start-Sleep -Seonds 1
```

You could also do string matching to find elements to do stuff to. For example on this multi doc page site

```
$url = 'https://www.aircanada.com/ca/en/ado/profile/sign-in.html'

# Get form elements
($FormElements = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -SessionVariable fe)  

# List all form objects 
$FormElements.Forms
$FormElements.InputFields
$FormElements.ParsedHtml
$FormElements.Content
$FormElements.Scripts


# Get all page source elements
$FormElements.AllElements

$FormElements.AllElements | 
Select-Object -Expand OuterText

$FormElements.AllElements | 
Select-Object -Expand InnerText


# Get elements by string match
$FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$_.TagName -eq "input"}

# Get all page button elements
$FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$_.TagName -eq "Button"}

$FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$_.TagName -eq "Button"} | 
Select-Object outerHTML

$FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$_.TagName -eq "Button"} | 
Select-Object -Expand OuterText

$FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$_.TagName -eq "Button"} | 
Select-Object -Expand InnerText


# Get only the submit button that matches the criteria
($FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$_.TagName -eq "Button"} | 
Select-Object -Property outerHTML) -Match 'SIGN IN'

$FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$_.TagName -eq "Button"} | 
Select-Object -Property * | 
Where innerText -eq 'SIGN IN'
```

***Update per your BookinAgent comment***

```
$FormElements.Forms
$FormElements.InputFields.FindById('bookingAgent')
<#
# Results

Id           Method Action                              Fields                                                                                
--           ------ ------                              ------                                                                                
             get    /ca/en/ado/home/search-results.html {[searchbox_01, ]}                                                                    
             get    /ca/en/ado/home/search-results.html {[searchbox_011, ]}                                                                   
             get    /ca/en/ado/home/search-results.html {[searchbox_0111, ]}                                                                  
adoLoginForm post                                       {[agencyIATA, ], [agencyID, ], [bookingAgent, ], [password, ], [rememberAgencyInfo, ]}
adoLoginForm post                                       {[agencyIATA, ], [agencyID, ], [bookingAgent, ], [password, ], [rememberAgencyInfo, ]}
bookingAgent   
#>



# Get elements by string match
$FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$_.TagName -eq "input"} | 
Select-String -Pattern 'BookingAgent'



# Get all page button elements
$FormElements.AllElements | 
Where{$_.TagName -eq "Button"} | 
Select-String -Pattern 'BookingAgent'
```

Comment: To see the elements, I just right-clicked in the username field and selected "Inspect element" using IE. The selection I pasted minus some additional DIVs is what was displayed.

I see in your AirCanada example that it appears similar in that the bookingAgent field is nested down a few levels. Let me digest what you have written. Thanks!

Comment: postanote, in the aircanada example, how would you populate the bookingagent field?

Thanks.

Comment: That is a input box and a button. The code for that is already in what I provided. Just filter for that. See my update for you.

Comment: ok, I can now get this output:


@{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<INPUT onfocus=onFocusUsername() onblur=onBlurUsername() class=moto-username-input value=Username name=loginUsername>; outerText=; 
tagName=INPUT; onfocus=onFocusUsername(); onblur=onBlurUsername(); class=moto-username-input; value=Username; name=loginUsername}

Comment: Would I use $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById to set it?

Comment: If the is the input element you discovered then yes, but since I have no idea what website you are working with, that just an assumption. I have been assuming that the reason you never showed the site you were hitting, that it was some internal on, or the like. Hence the reason for me using ohter urls.

Comment: How do I do a line break or carriage return on these comments? The help says to use two spaces but it doesn't seem to be working. Thanks.